# Math drupal module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to learn to write drupal modules and am working on writing a simple math module http://nodeone.se/en/the-math-question-module

I've got the GUI down fine but seem to be having issues with the actual math.  I never seem to get the correct answer because I think it loads a new set of questions before it checks the current answer.

Here's what I have so far:

```
   <?php

/**
 * @file
 * Tests users on their math skills through a series of question and answers
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function math_question_menu() {
  // add new navigation menu item
  $items['math_question'] = array(
    'title' =>  'Math questions',
    'description' => 'Test you math skills with these questions.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('math_question_page'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer_site_configuration'),
  );
  return $items; 
}
  $val1 = rand(1,10);
  $val2 = rand(1,10);
  variable_set('val1', $val1);
  variable_set('val2', $val2);
/**
 * Builds the form for configuring Math Questions.
 */
function math_question_page() {
  global $user;
  $num1 = variable_get('val1');
  $num2 = variable_get('val2');
  $total = $num1 + $num2;
  variable_set('total',$total);
  $form['math_question'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'What is ' . $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ', ' . 
      check_plain($user->name) . '?',
    );
  $form['answer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Answer'),
    );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Check my answer'),
    );
  return $form;
}

function math_question_page_validate($form, $form_state) {
  if (empty($form['answer']['#value'])) {
     form_error($form['answer'], t('This field is required.'));
   }
   if ($form['answer']['#value'] == 
      variable_get('total')) {
    $msg = t('Good job!');
    $type = 'status';
  } 
  else {
    $msg = t('Try again...');
    $type = 'error';
  }
  drupal_set_message(check_plain($msg), $type);
}
```

---

modified code:
.
.

```
    /**
     * Builds the form for configuring Math Questions.
     */
   function math_question_page() {
      global $user;
        $val1 = rand(1,10);
        $val2 = rand(1,10);
       $total = $val1 + $val2;
      $form['math_question'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => 'What is ' . $val1 . ' + ' . $val2 . ', ' . 
          check_plain($user->name) . '?',
        );
      $form['answer'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Answer'),
        );
      $form['total'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $total,
        );
      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Check my answer'),
        );
      return $form;
    }

    function math_question_page_validate($form, $form_state) {
      if (empty($form['answer']['#value'])) {
         form_error($form['answer'], t('This field is required.'));
       }
       if ($form['answer']['#value'] == 
          $form['total']['#value']) {
        $msg = t('Good job!');
        $type = 'status';
      } 
      else {
       $msg = t('Try again...');
       $type = 'error';
      }
      drupal_set_message(check_plain($msg), $type);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the validation function `math_question_page_validate()`, you should access the values from $form_state variable, not from $form.

eg:

```
if (!$form_state['values']['answer'] == $form_state['values']['total']) {
    form_set_error('answer', $error);
}
```

<del>You can also store the answer in $form_state variable to pass it to the validation function (no need to store the value in $form). if you store it as $form_state['total'], you can access it in the same way (given below).</del>

<del>if (!$form_state['total'] == $form_state['values']['answer']) {form_set_error('answer', $error);}</del>

Thank you very much [papirrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277693/papirrin) for teaching [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308905/1767085).

I suggest to use variable_get() to keep the correct answer safe. The random value you keep in the form will not survive the form regeneration.

My working code here.

```
/**
* Builds the form for configuring Math Questions.
*/
function math_question_page($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
    $val1 = rand(1,10);
    $val2 = rand(1,10);
    $total = $val1 + $val2;
    // Store the correct answer safely away from this form
  if (!variable_get('math_question_answer',FALSE)) {
    variable_set('math_question_answer', $total);
  }
  $form['math_question'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'What is ' . $val1 . ' + ' . $val2 . ', ' . 
      check_plain($user->name) . '?',
    );
  $form['answer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Answer'),
    );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Check my answer'),
    );
  $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}

function math_question_page_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form['answer']['#value'])) {
     form_set_error('answer', t('This field is required.'));
  } 
  else {
    if ($form_state['values']['answer'] == variable_get('math_question_answer')) {
      $msg = t('Good job!');
      $type = 'status';
    } 
    else {
      $msg = t('Try again...');
      $type = 'error';
    }
    drupal_set_message(check_plain($msg), $type);
  }
  variable_del('math_question_answer');
}
```

Comment: I tried changing to $form_state but am still having the same problem, The value for $total is not fixed and changes before it checks for the correct answer.

Comment: In which array are you storing the variable $total? Post your updated code with $form_state, here in the comments.

Comment: I tried both yo suggestions but this code below has it in $form['total']                                                               `if ($form_state['values']['answer'] == 
          {
           $form_state['values']['total']) {
        $msg = t('Good job!');
        $type = 'status';
      }`

Comment: My answer updated with the help of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15308905/1767085) by papirrin.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal redirects after form submission so your form fields (altogether with your form) are recreated before the validation is called. See details about that in [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22893/14480).

Your form is created with math_question_page, which does not take any form_state arguments. If you had form_state, then you could detect that math_question_page has not been submitted yet and just keep the state of the last call (last random values).

In order to call math_question_page with a form_state argument, you can use [drupal_build_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) instead of drupal_get_form in your menu.

Comment: Use drupal_build_form instead of page_validate?

Comment: no, instead of drupal_get_form. I reedited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Hmm, when I replace `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',` with 
`'page callback' => 'drupal_build_form("math-question-page", &$form_state)',` my page no longer loads so I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the $total in the global variable 'total', try storing it as a hidden field on your form (unless you are worried about your users cheating). You can write:

'#type' => 'hidden,

to create a hidden 'total' field and then check for that value in validate so prevent total to be overwritten.

Comment: Install the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use the dpm() to print the values of your hidden total and answer fields. It may help you spot another problem.

Comment: I've already done that but still can't figure it out, There is a problem with the $total, It's recalculating on page load before checking for the correct answer but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning to write drupal modules too (Started the tutorial series 2 weeks ago).
I tried to do this same module , and i think that the implementation which saves the random values in the database is NOT correct. The first thing asked in the exercise is this :

> 1. Any user visiting the /question path will get a simple add-two-numbers question, such as "What is 4 + 9?".
>
> So acces arguments for the page should be 'access arguments' => array('access content') not 'access arguments' => array('administer_site_configuration').

This comes with the following issue : If there are 2 (or more) users browsing at the same moment this page , the latest user overwrites the values in the database , so the other users won't be able to complete the "question" because his answer will not be equal to the answer in the database. Saving values to database is NOT a option in this case...

Meantime I am trying to make it work without the database , but i have the same situation as this question's starter , the form overwrites the values when i submit it (so , error thrown because the answer is wrong ).

If i'll manage to complete it i'll post the code here , or if someone else managed to complete it without variable_set() and variable_get() , i ask them to post the code here :)

Comment: Ok i managed to get all the code CORRECTLY Working. You can view it here if you want : https://github.com/bogdy2p/DM_math_question/